Jekyll build errror on Vercel project
I have a Jekyll website hosted on a Bitbucket repository.
And I have a Vercel project that runs that website to generate the static files.
Some days ago, it works great, but today it started to fail with this error message.
I don't kwon, why this is not working now.
It work great on local, only doesn't work when Vercel try to build it.
Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
Cloning bitbucket.org/kaplangabriel/jekyll-blog (Branch: main, Commit: 72555ed)
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 3.940s
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 33.7.1
Warning: Detected "engines": { "node": ">= 0.10.0" } in your `package.json` that will automatically upgrade when a new major Node.js Version is released. Learn More: http://vercel.link/node-version
Installing dependencies...
Fetching https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching rake 13.2.1
Installing rake 13.2.1
Fetching bigdecimal 3.1.7
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.2.3
Installing bigdecimal 3.1.7 with native extensions
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.2.3
Fetching connection_pool 2.4.1
Installing connection_pool 2.4.1
Fetching drb 2.2.1
Installing drb 2.2.1
Fetching minitest 5.22.3
Installing minitest 5.22.3
Fetching public_suffix 5.0.5
Installing public_suffix 5.0.5
Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
Installing multi_json 1.15.0
Fetching colorator 1.1.0
Installing colorator 1.1.0
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.8.0
Installing http_parser.rb 0.8.0 with native extensions
Fetching ffi 1.16.3
Installing ffi 1.16.3 with native extensions
Fetching forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Installing forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Fetching gemoji 4.1.0
Installing gemoji 4.1.0
Fetching google-protobuf 4.26.1 (x86_64-linux)
Installing google-protobuf 4.26.1 (x86_64-linux)
Fetching racc 1.7.3
Installing racc 1.7.3 with native extensions
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.2
Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.2
Fetching rexml 3.2.6
Installing rexml 3.2.6
Fetching liquid 4.0.4
Installing liquid 4.0.4
Fetching mercenary 0.4.0
Installing mercenary 0.4.0
Fetching rouge 4.2.1
Installing rouge 4.2.1
Fetching safe_yaml 1.0.5
Installing safe_yaml 1.0.5
Fetching unicode-display_width 2.5.0
Installing unicode-display_width 2.5.0
Fetching webrick 1.8.1
Installing webrick 1.8.1
Fetching jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Installing jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Fetching i18n 1.14.4
Installing i18n 1.14.4
Fetching tzinfo 2.0.6
Installing tzinfo 2.0.6
Fetching net-http-persistent 4.0.2
Installing net-http-persistent 4.0.2
Fetching addressable 2.8.6
Installing addressable 2.8.6
Fetching net-http 0.4.1
Installing net-http 0.4.1
Fetching em-websocket 0.5.3
Installing em-websocket 0.5.3
Fetching pathutil 0.16.2
Installing pathutil 0.16.2
Fetching sass-embedded 1.75.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
Installing sass-embedded 1.75.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
Fetching nokogiri 1.16.4 (x86_64-linux)
Installing nokogiri 1.16.4 (x86_64-linux)
Fetching kramdown 2.4.0
Installing kramdown 2.4.0
Fetching terminal-table 3.0.2
Installing terminal-table 3.0.2
Fetching activesupport 7.1.3.2
Installing activesupport 7.1.3.2
Fetching faraday-net_http 3.1.0
Installing faraday-net_http 3.1.0
Fetching jekyll-sass-converter 3.0.0
Installing jekyll-sass-converter 3.0.0
Fetching kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Installing kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Fetching html-pipeline 2.14.3
Installing html-pipeline 2.14.3
Fetching faraday 2.9.0
Installing faraday 2.9.0
Fetching faraday-net_http_persistent 2.1.0
Installing faraday-net_http_persistent 2.1.0
Fetching faraday-retry 2.2.1
Installing faraday-retry 2.2.1
Fetching sawyer 0.9.2
Installing sawyer 0.9.2
Fetching algolia 2.3.4
Installing algolia 2.3.4
Fetching octokit 4.25.1
Installing octokit 4.25.1
Fetching jekyll-gist 1.5.0
Installing jekyll-gist 1.5.0
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
Fetching listen 3.9.0
Installing listen 3.9.0
Fetching jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Installing jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Fetching jekyll 4.3.3
Installing jekyll 4.3.3
Fetching jekyll-feed 0.17.0
Fetching jekyll-include-cache 0.2.1
Installing jekyll-feed 0.17.0
Installing jekyll-include-cache 0.2.1
Fetching jekyll-sitemap 1.4.0
Fetching jemoji 0.13.0
Installing jemoji 0.13.0
Installing jekyll-sitemap 1.4.0
Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
Post-install message from html-pipeline:
-------------------------------------------------
Thank you for installing html-pipeline!
You must bundle Filter gem dependencies.
See html-pipeline README.md for more details.
https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline#dependencies
-------------------------------------------------
Installing dependencies...
added 136 packages in 8s
60 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
/ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:222:in `rescue in load_spec_files': https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git (at v1.2.7@9cb13a8) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. (Bundler::GitError)
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:218:in `load_spec_files'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:108:in `local_specs'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:185:in `specs'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:97:in `materialize_for_installation'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:281:in `map!'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:281:in `specs_for_dependency'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:34:in `block in for'
    from <internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:22:in `for'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:121:in `materialize'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:579:in `materialize'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `specs'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:270:in `specs_for'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:159:in `with_level'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:111:in `silence'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from <internal:/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from /vercel/path0/vendor/bin/jekyll:25:in `<main>'
/ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:210:in `load_spec_files': The path `/vercel/path0/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/gems/eventmachine-9cb13a8a6236` does not exist. (Bundler::PathError)
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:219:in `load_spec_files'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:108:in `local_specs'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:185:in `specs'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:97:in `materialize_for_installation'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:281:in `map!'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:281:in `specs_for_dependency'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:34:in `block in for'
    from <internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:22:in `for'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:121:in `materialize'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:579:in `materialize'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `specs'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:270:in `specs_for'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:159:in `with_level'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:111:in `silence'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from <internal:/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from /vercel/path0/vendor/bin/jekyll:25:in `<main>'
Error: Command "jekyll build" exited with 1

This is my Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
# gem "jekyll", "~> 4.2.1"
# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
# gem "minima", "~> 2.5"
# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
gem "jekyll-include-cache", group: :jekyll_plugins
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-paginate"
  gem "jekyll-sitemap"
  gem "jekyll-gist"
  gem "jekyll-feed"
  gem "jemoji"
  gem 'algolia', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.4'
end

# Windows and JRuby does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# and associated library.
platforms :mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby do
  gem "tzinfo", "~> 1.2"
  gem "tzinfo-data"
end

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
gem "webrick"
gem 'eventmachine', '1.2.7', git: 'https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git', tag: 'v1.2.7'
gem 'faraday-retry'

This is my Gemfile.lock
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activesupport (7.1.3.2)
      base64
      bigdecimal
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.5)
      drb
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      mutex_m
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    addressable (2.8.6)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    algolia (2.3.4)
      faraday (>= 0.15, < 3)
      faraday-net_http_persistent (>= 0.15, < 3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      net-http-persistent
    base64 (0.2.0)
    bigdecimal (3.1.7)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.3)
    connection_pool (2.4.1)
    drb (2.2.1)
    em-websocket (0.5.3)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    faraday (2.9.0)
      faraday-net_http (>= 2.0, < 3.2)
    faraday-net_http (3.1.0)
      net-http
    faraday-net_http_persistent (2.1.0)
      faraday (~> 2.5)
      net-http-persistent (~> 4.0)
    faraday-retry (2.2.1)
      faraday (~> 2.0)
    ffi (1.16.3-x64-mingw-ucrt)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    gemoji (4.1.0)
    google-protobuf (4.26.1-x64-mingw-ucrt)
      rake (>= 13)
    html-pipeline (2.14.3)
      activesupport (>= 2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4)
    http_parser.rb (0.8.0)
    i18n (1.14.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (4.3.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-sass-converter (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.1)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.0)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (>= 0.3.6, < 0.5)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      terminal-table (>= 1.8, < 4.0)
      webrick (~> 1.7)
    jekyll-feed (0.17.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-gist (1.5.0)
      octokit (~> 4.2)
    jekyll-include-cache (0.2.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
    jekyll-sass-converter (3.0.0)
      sass-embedded (~> 1.54)
    jekyll-sitemap (1.4.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    jemoji (0.13.0)
      gemoji (>= 3, < 5)
      html-pipeline (~> 2.2)
      jekyll (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    kramdown (2.4.0)
      rexml
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    liquid (4.0.4)
    listen (3.9.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.4.0)
    minitest (5.22.3)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    mutex_m (0.2.0)
    net-http (0.4.1)
      uri
    net-http-persistent (4.0.2)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2)
    nokogiri (1.16.4-x64-mingw-ucrt)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    octokit (4.25.1)
      faraday (>= 1, < 3)
      sawyer (~> 0.9)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (5.0.5)
    racc (1.7.3)
    rake (13.2.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    rouge (4.2.1)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sass-embedded (1.75.0-x64-mingw-ucrt)
      google-protobuf (>= 3.25, < 5.0)
    sawyer (0.9.2)
      addressable (>= 2.3.5)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 3)
    terminal-table (3.0.2)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.1.1, < 3)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
    uri (0.13.0)
    webrick (1.8.1)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw-ucrt

DEPENDENCIES
  algolia (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.4)
  eventmachine
  faraday-retry
  jekyll-feed
  jekyll-gist
  jekyll-include-cache
  jekyll-paginate
  jekyll-sitemap
  jemoji
  tzinfo (~> 1.2)
  tzinfo-data
  wdm (~> 0.1.1)
  webrick

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.6

I changed the eventmachine line for this gem 'eventmachine' and I get this new error
/ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:596:in `materialize': Could not find jekyll-include-cache-0.2.1, jekyll-paginate-1.1.0, jekyll-sitemap-1.4.0, jekyll-gist-1.5.0, jekyll-feed-0.17.0, jemoji-0.13.0, algolia-2.3.4, webrick-1.8.1, eventmachine-1.2.7, faraday-retry-2.2.1, jekyll-4.3.3, octokit-4.25.1, gemoji-4.1.0, html-pipeline-2.14.3, faraday-2.9.0, faraday-net_http_persistent-2.1.0, multi_json-1.15.0, net-http-persistent-4.0.2, addressable-2.8.6, colorator-1.1.0, em-websocket-0.5.3, i18n-1.14.4, jekyll-sass-converter-3.0.0, jekyll-watch-2.2.1, kramdown-2.4.0, kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0, liquid-4.0.4, mercenary-0.4.0, pathutil-0.16.2, rouge-4.2.1, safe_yaml-1.0.5, terminal-table-3.0.2, sawyer-0.9.2, activesupport-7.1.3.2, nokogiri-1.16.4-x86_64-linux, faraday-net_http-3.1.0, connection_pool-2.4.1, public_suffix-5.0.5, http_parser.rb-0.8.0, concurrent-ruby-1.2.3, sass-embedded-1.75.0-x86_64-linux-gnu, listen-3.9.0, forwardable-extended-2.6.0, unicode-display_width-2.5.0, bigdecimal-3.1.7, drb-2.2.1, minitest-5.22.3, tzinfo-2.0.6, net-http-0.4.1, google-protobuf-4.26.1-x86_64-linux, rb-fsevent-0.11.2, rb-inotify-0.10.1, rake-13.2.1, ffi-1.16.3 in cached gems or installed locally (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `specs'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:270:in `specs_for'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:159:in `with_level'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:111:in `silence'
    from /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from <internal:/ruby33/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from /vercel/path0/vendor/bin/jekyll:25:in `<main>'
Error: Command "jekyll build" exited with 1


Have you run bundle install? (There's an error message that says /ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.9/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:222:in rescue in load_spec_files': https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git (at v1.2.7@9cb13a8) is not yet checked out. Run bundle install first. (Bundler::GitError)`.)

In vercel, the install command is bundle install

Can you provide the content of your gemfile? If it works locally but not remote, it may help if you fix all your gem versions.

Yes, I updated the question with the Gemfile

Could you share your Gemfile.lock file?

Yes, I updated the question with the Gemfile.lock

try replacing the following and try again
gem 'eventmachine', '1.2.7', git: 'https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git', tag: 'v1.2.7'

with
gem 'eventmachine'


I tryed and I get a new error, I updated my question

Update Gemfile with above. Delete gemfile.lock and bundle again.

Based on your Gemfile.lock file, the bundle was bundled with 2.3.6, but Vercel is trying to use 2.5.9.
You have a few options:

Try downgrading your Bundler version to 2.3.6, as specified in the lockfile
Remove your Gemfile.lock, and perform another bundle install command. You will have to commit the new Gemfile.lock to SCM with the changes. (This may not be what you want, as this will also pull any newer versions of other gems, but if you don't mind updating other gems as well, go for it)
Try removing the BUNDLED WITH section of the Gemfile.lock and execute bundle install


I have seen this in other projects, related to dependencies. Here are some ideas for troubleshooting.
Vercel might be experiencing temporary network issues or restrictions that prevent accessing GitHub repositories. There may have been changes in network policies or firewall settings on Vercel’s side that you are not aware of.
Vercel could be using a cached build environment that has corrupted or incomplete data. This might not reflect changes you’ve made recently.
As mentioned by ddavinson above, there could be differences in the environment (like installed Git version, Bundler version, or Ruby version) between your local setup and Vercel.
You remove the commit ref and try with
gem 'eventmachine', git: 'https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git', tag: 'v1.2.7'

As a fallback and if the issue with the Git repository persists, consider using the version of eventmachine available on RubyGems instead of a Git-based version for stability and simplicity:
gem 'eventmachine', '1.2.7'

Try clearing the build cache on Vercel under settings (General/Build) or via CLI:
vercel --prod --force

You can also run bundle install on vercel in verbose mode, by editing the vercel.json configuration file:
{
  "builds": [{
    "src": "Gemfile",
    "use": "@vercel/ruby",
    "config": { "bundleInstallCommand": "bundle install --verbose" }
  }]
}

Last way out: Post a GitHub issue on https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues or contact the Vercel support at https://vercel.com/help.
